# Create a node of a certain type using neography

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography

I'm successfully using the [neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) gem, with one small problem. I cannot seem to specify the type of node I want. The API I'm using is:

```
@neo.create_node({doors: 4, brand: 'ford', model: 'fiesta'})
```

I want to be able to do the equivalent of:

```
CREATE (c:Car {doors: 4, brand: 'ford', model: 'fiesta'})
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/blob/46be2bb3c66aea14e707b1e6f82937e65f686ccc/lib/neography/rest/nodes.rb#L23-L37) this doesn't seem to be possible, at least not via create_node. Thanks in advance for the help!